# Unable to integrate a database (with images) into a Django project

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying integrate a database full of questions (with images) into a sqlite3 database in Django. After running 'inspectdb', I pushed the model at the appropriate place.

My model looks like this:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    main_ques = models.IntegerField(db_column='Main_ques', blank=True, null=True)  
    sub_ques = models.TextField(db_column='Sub_ques', blank=True, null=True)  
    page_num = models.IntegerField(db_column='Page_num', blank=True, null=True)  
    marks = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    topic = models.TextField(db_column='Topic', blank=True, null=True)  
    subques_images = models.ImageField(db_column='Subques_images', blank=True, null=True)  
    mainques_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'questions'
```

And my 0001_initial.py looks like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Questions',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('main_ques', models.IntegerField(blank=True, db_column='Main_ques', null=True)),
                ('sub_ques', models.TextField(blank=True, db_column='Sub_ques', null=True)),
                ('page_num', models.IntegerField(blank=True, db_column='Page_num', null=True)),
                ('marks', models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('topic', models.TextField(blank=True, db_column='Topic', null=True)),
                ('subques_images', models.ImageField(blank=True, db_column='Subques_images', null=True, upload_to='')),
                ('mainques_image', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'questions',
                'managed': True,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

[The admin page looks like this..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/105Kl.png)

But after that it says, this

[Error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKiLb.png)

I am pasting the error message below:

```
OperationalError at /admin/sql_inte/questions/
no such column: questions.id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sql_inte/questions/
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: questions.id
Exception Location: /Users/BivashChakraborty/PycharmProjects/database/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 423, in execute
Python Executable:  /Users/BivashChakraborty/PycharmProjects/database/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/BivashChakraborty/PycharmProjects/database',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/BivashChakraborty/PycharmProjects/database/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

And when I try to run migrate, it says

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "questions" already exists
```

Help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: update your `view.py` file

Answer (score 0):

Did you apply your migration (so your code actually affected the DB you work with)?

`$ python manage.py migrate`

Have a look at [django migration tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/)

Comment: Done that a thousand times!!! Probably doing something wrong can't figure it out. Will check out the link you sent though.